# JSX object representation of rows

Tags: node.js, reactjs, jsx

If I want to be able to render several rows like below from one function call at once using `JSX`.

**What does the code for `ObjectRow` in  `rows.push(<ObjectRow />);` have to look like?**

```
var rows = [];
for (var i=0; i < numrows; i++) {
    rows.push(<ObjectRow />);
}
return <tbody>{rows}</tbody>;
```

I want each row to look like this:

```
<tr>
            <td>{}</td>
            <td>{}</td>
            <td>{}</td>
            <td>{}</td>
            <td>{}</td>
            <td>{}</td>
            <td>{}</td>
            <td>{}</td>
            <td>{}</td>
            <td>{}</td>
            <td>{5}</td>                
            <td className={lastClass}>{5}</td>
            <td className={changeClass}>{5} <span className={iconClass} aria-hidden="true"></span></td>
            <td>{5}</td>
            <td>{5}</td>
            <td>{}</td>
            <td>{}</td>
            <td>{}</td>
            <td>{}</td>
            <td>{}</td>
            <td>{}</td>
            <td>{}</td>
            <td>{}</td>
            <td>{}</td>
            <td>{}</td>
 </tr>
```

Finally I want to render all these rows:

```
var StockRow = React.createClass({

    things: function(){
        var rows = [];
        for (var i=0; i < numrows; i++) {
            rows.push(<ObjectRow />);
        }
        return <tbody>{rows}</tbody>;
    },
...
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do this. Also, you need to send data (as props to `ObjectRow`) to display for each row as well. I have created a fiddle for same.

In the fiddle below I have added table headers and some more data so that the columns are clearly distinguishable.
Variable `tableData` holds data came back from server.

https://jsfiddle.net/birjubaba/cby5pxcc/3/